# Simplest way to write a log message and display in Perfview

Tags: c#, .net, etw, eventlog-source, perfview

I need the to write a log message and capture that in [PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview). I would like to avoid using `EventLog` or `EventSource` because they are quite invasive: they require registering a new source or ETW provider, which leaves leftovers in the system.

Ideally I just want to call `Debug.WriteLine` (which uses [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx)), but it seems that PerfView cannot collect it. Or is there some ETW provider that sees debug messages?

If you have an answer, please state the two parts of the solution:

1. What should I write in C#, and
2. How to configure PerfView to capture it (if there is some ETW provider, just name it).

Comment: DebugView is the tool for reading Debug.WriteLines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview

Comment: I know, but I need PerfView. DebugView won't show everything else that is happing.

Comment: Then you want to configure a [TraceListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.eventprovidertracelistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) via the [app.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-use-tracesource-and-filters-with-trace-listeners)

Comment: EventSource doesn't require any registration.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, but it creates a new ETW provider in the system and requires me to learn the GUID in order to use in the PerfView. I would like a less intrusive solution where I can just trace something and it will appear.

Comment: I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprint. Maybe is possible to configure PerfView to capture that?

Comment: no, I already requested an ETW provider for debug calls, but MS refuses this. I've posted the simple code to do what you want via EventSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use [EventSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource?view=netframework-4.7.2). Here you don't need to deal with GUIDs and registration to system.

```
public sealed class MinimalEventSource : EventSource
{
    public class Tasks
    {
        public const EventTask Information = (EventTask)1;
    }

    public static MinimalEventSource Log = new MinimalEventSource();

    [Event(1, Message = "{0}", Opcode = EventOpcode.Info, Task = Tasks.Information)]
    public void Information(string message)
    {
        if (IsEnabled())
        {
            WriteEvent(1, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Lof the data with `MinimalEventSource.Log.Information("my debug info");` and capture them with perfview with `PerfView /OnlyProviders=*MinimalEventSource`. The imprtant thing is the `*`  . Eventsource logs the Manifest with the definitions via [ManifestEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316470/1466046) which gets added to the ETL, so no manifest registration is required.