# How to create dll assembly for manifest ETW

Tags: c#, logging, etw

I'm using ETW. I wanna register my event source with using wevtutil. I created manifest using EventSource class:

```
string manifestFile = "manifest.xml";
public Registrer()
{
    var assemblyFile = ""; //How to create assembly file???
    var manifestText = EventSource.GenerateManifest(typeof(ExceptionHundler), assemblyFile);

    using (var wr = new StreamWriter(manifestFile))
    {
        wr.Write(manifestText);
    }
    RegistrEventSource();
}
private void RegistrEventSource()
{
    var cmdCommandForCreatingEventSource = $@"wevtutil.exe im ""{manifestFile}""";
    Console.WriteLine(ExecuteCmdCommand(cmdCommandForCreatingEventSource));
}
private string ExecuteCmdCommand(string strCommand, bool runAsAdmin = true)
{
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    if (runAsAdmin)
        cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "runus";
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCommand);
    cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
    cmd.StandardInput.Close();
    cmd.WaitForExit();
    return cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

My question is how to create assembly file for EventSource? (Without using packages from nuget). I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WES/message-compiler--mc-exe- , but some computers doesn't have mc.exe. And in each computer which I'm using my project I need to fix mc.exe (by installing SDK ). What does contains assembly file and is there any way to create this?

Comment: ignoe this registering. [here is the only code you need to create an EventSource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54114220/1466046)