# How to fix missing EventSource traces in the logman sessions

Tags: c#, .net, etw-eventsource

I have a sample piece of code which I borrowed from MSDN 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource?view=netframework-4.7.2

All I did in addition to this was to import this code into Visual studio console app.

To fire up the tracing session I tried both:

```
netsh trace start provider={3CADFCE4-5E22-4102-BDC2-5AEA4198CD04}
```

and even tried
`logman create trace sess -pf guids.txt -bs 1000 -nb 100 256 -ow -o tracefiles` (guids.txt has this only guid)

Once the ETL is spit out I tried using WPA/netsh trace convert and Message Analyzer to open them. None of these shows these events.

What is wrong with here ?

```
[EventSource(Name = "MyLogger", Guid = "3CADFCE4-5E22-4102-BDC2-5AEA4198CD04")]
class MyCompanyEventSource : EventSource
{
    public static MyCompanyEventSource Log = new MyCompanyEventSource();

    [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void Startup() { WriteEvent(1); }

    [Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void OpenFileStart(string fileName) { WriteEvent(2, fileName); }

    [Event(3, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void LogString(string text) { WriteEvent(3, text); } 
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            string name = MyCompanyEventSource.GetName(typeof(MyCompanyEventSource));
            IEnumerable<EventSource> eventSources = MyCompanyEventSource.GetSources();
            MyCompanyEventSource.Log.Startup();
            MyCompanyEventSource.Log.OpenFileStart("My Filename");
            MyCompanyEventSource.Log.LogString("Random string");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        } while (true);

    }
```

I expect the results to show up but all I see is :

```
[0]8664.6194::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 [MSNT_SystemTrace]
[0]8664.6194::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 [MSNT_SystemTrace]
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
[0]0000.0000::‎2019‎-‎04‎-‎03 21:18:34.125 []***
```

Comment: use [perfview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54114220/1466046) to capture the events: `PerfView /OnlyProviders=*MyLogger`

Comment: have you tried perfview or not?